# Ubuntu 16.04 kodi jarvis 16 video problems

Tags: drivers, video

I was having problems with kodi jarvis playing slow video and no sound i have a dell inspirion 1545 does anyone have a solution or help on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system is fully updated. Regular updates include the open source drivers for Intel Graphics.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Did that twice and my Internet speed is 20mbs so i know that can't be the problem.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment about internet speed. What does it have to with anything? The point is having your system fully updated, - hence the commands to make sure of that - because most video issues are related to graphics drivers. Now, if your problem happens when playing files from the *network* that's another beast entirely and if so, please edit your question and include all the relevant information.

Comment: Never mind celticwarrior you got it i restarted after updating and it works great thanks!

Comment: That's nice. If it helped then consider accepting the answer. Thank you.